# May we get a transition kernel from a product measurable function that is positive, non-decreasing and right-continuous in one of its variables?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> If $V(s,\omega)$ is product measurable on $\mathcal{B}[0,t] \otimes \mathcal{F}_t$, and is non-decreasing, non-negative and right-continuous as a function $s \mapsto V(s,\omega)$, then is the map $\omega \mapsto \mu_\omega(B)$ measurable, where $\mu_\omega$ is the unique measure $\mu_\omega((a,b])=V(b,\omega)-V(a,\omega)$?

That is, for every $\omega$ it is known that we may get a measure on $[0,t]$ but may we also get a transition kernel from $\Omega$ to $[0,t]$?

---

I can see the following: from product measurability we get that $\omega \mapsto V(b,\omega)$ and $\omega \mapsto V(a,\omega)$ are measurable and thus also $\omega \mapsto \mu_\omega((a,b])$. Further we have that any set in $\mathcal{B}[0,t]$ may be written as a countable union of sets of the form $(a,b]$. May we deduce the desired conclusion from this?

Most grateful for any help provided!